# How to display image in python docx template (docxtpl)? Django Python

Tags: python, django, image, templates, python-docx

I am using python-docx-template (docxtpl) to generate a `.docx` file.
With this data:

```
docente= {
   "id":145,
   "lugar_de_nacimiento":"Loja",
   "fecha_de_nacimiento":"1973-04-14",
   "ciudad":"Loja",
   "foto_web_low":"https://sica.utpl.edu.ec/media/uploads/docentes/fotos/web/low/1102904313_low.jpg"
}
```

I have a function where I pass the image `docente['foto_web_low']` to the `context` and the path of the template:

```
from docxtpl import DocxTemplate, InlineImage
from docx.shared import Mm

def generaraDocumento(request):
    response = HttpResponse(content_type='application/msword')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="cv.docx"'

    doc = DocxTemplate(str(settings.BASE_DIR) + '/cv_api/templates/docx_filename.docx')
    imagen = docente['foto_web_low'] 

    context = {'imagen': imagen}

    doc.render(context)
    doc.save(response)

    return response
```

The template where I have the image that I want to show `docx_filename.docx` has this:

The template where I have the data that I want to show `docx_filename.docx` has this:

```
Image: {{ imagen }}
```

When the document is generated, I only get the URL address and not the image, in my template it returns this:

```
Image: https://sica.utpl.edu.ec/media/uploads/docentes/fotos/web/low/1102904313_low.jpg
```

How can I make the image appear in the document `.docx (docxtpl)`. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

The image has to be an instance of `docxtpl.InlineImage` ([see docs](https://docxtpl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#inline-image)).

Another important thing is that the image must be present on the disk. `docxtpl` doesn't support reading images from a url.

Example:

```
from docxtpl import InlineImage
from docx.shared import Mm


doc = DocxTemplate(str(settings.BASE_DIR) + '/cv_api/templates/docx_filename.docx')

# The image must be already saved on the disk
# reading images from url is not supported
imagen = InlineImage(doc, '/path/to/image/file.jpg', width=Mm(20)) # width is in millimetres

context = {'imagen': imagen}

# ... the rest of the code remains the same ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Resize the image first, before add it
make it fit to your space

```
from PIL import Image

img = Image.open("image-path")
newimg = img.resize((250, 250))
newimg.save("tmplogo.png")
```

then use the new sized image which name tmplogo.png

```
doc = DocxTemplate("Base.docx")
dic = {"logo": InlineImage(doc, "tmplogo.png")}

doc.render(dic)
doc.save("test.docx")
```

Answer (score 0):

You're currently linking the variable foto_web_low to the url and not to an actual image. You will need to download the image first, and then attach it. The code below is not tested, but should be in the right direction:

First, dowload the image:

```
 response = requests.get("https://The_URL_of_the_picture.jpg")
file = open("the_image.png", "wb")
file.write(response.content)
file.close()
```

And then simply add the image to your variable in the context:

```
docente= {
   "id":145,
   ...
   "foto_web_low":"the_image.png",
  ...
}
```